# Jest marks test as success even if there was an assert

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, assert

How to make this sort of test fail in Jest? Is there a global setting for making any test with a failed-assert fail in Jest?

```
test('Assert', () =>
{
    console.assert(false, "This should fail the test");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5634

The suggestions include checking your environment or node version.
If that doesn't work, you can add the following to your test setup file:

```
console.assert = (statement, message) => {
   if (!statement) throw new Error(message);
};
```

Comment: Is it [the correct link](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5634)? I've got 500